# How to send combined junit test results details from multiple jenkins jobs as email after the jobs ran properly

Tags: jenkins, junit, dashboard, jelly, email-ext

I have total five jobs in jenkins. Lets assume the jobs are as follows

1. Unit Tests
2. API Tests
3. Service Tests
4. UI Tests
5. Miscellaneous Tests

All the jobs generate junit report. I can publish those in each job level that is fine.

But Now my requirement is after all the jobs ran I want to send a consolidated email report to management which will contains how many tests ran for each job, out of which how many passed, how many fail and how many tests skipped. And in the below I will put total number of tests ran (which is the summation of number of test executed by each job), total number of test pass, total number of test failed, and if possible test statistic charts.

So My requirements are quite similar like I want to send the dashboard view of the jenkins in an email.

It will be great if someone can help me out. I tried jelly script but it only gives test result of a single job but I want the combine report for all job.